# How to validate/compare start time and end time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

```
let d0 = new Date('07/08/2021'+'10:00 AM') // already booked start date. 
let d1 = new Date('07/08/2021'+'10:00 PM') // already booked end date.
let d2 = new Date('07/08/2021'+'06:00 AM') // new user start date.
let d3 = new Date('07/08/2021'+'10:00 AM') // new user end date.

if ((d2 < d0 && d3 <= d0) || (d2 < d1 && d3 <= d1)) {
  return true;
}
```

*this condition is only working for in-between times. Suppose, one user enters 6AM-10AM(or)6AM-11PM. It didn't work.

Comment: The question is unclear. What's the expected behavior? Do you want to find out if both time ranges overlap? Overlaps can be checked with `d0 < d3 && d1 > d2` and `!(d0 < d3 && d1 > d2) === d0 >= d3 || d1 <= d2`.

Comment: `new Date('07/08/2021'+'10:00 AM')` almost certainly results in an invalid date.

Comment: this question is unclear, please edit your question to add more details and explain it more

Answer (score 0):

First need to clarify to validate the date object, like

```
const date2 = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
```

Based on your unclear question, if you want to compare the date/time A is early/late then date/time B. You can use `Date.parse()` to convert to miliseconds then compare. If you want to compare hours only, you can use `Date.getHours()` to compare.

Comment: If the timestamps are formatted as ISO 8601 then they compare lexically, so no need to convert to Date. Also, Date objects can be compared using `<` and `>` operators as they convert the operands to numbers. ;-)